# Protractor: how to click on a button until it is not displayed anymore

Tags: button, while-loop, protractor

With Protractor I'm trying to click a button until it is not displayed anymore. Currently this is while loop, where I'm trying to do so:

```
while(i < 5) {
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.loadMoreButton), 15000).then(function(result) {
        if(!result) {

            // wait for loader to disappear
            browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(page.loader), 15000);

            // click on load more button
            page.loadMoreButton.click();

            // wait for loader to disappear
            browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(page.loader), 15000);

            console.log("FOUND load more button!");

        } else {

            console.log("Did NOT find load more button!");
        }
    });

    i++;
};
```

I'm writing to a console only to see where exactly it failed. I don't know how many times this button will appear, so I know that the `while i < 5` is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, which works perfectly.

```
clickLoadMoreButtonUntilNotDisplayed = function() {
    // click on load more button until it is no longer visible
    loadMoreContainer.isDisplayed().then(visible => {
        if (visible) {
            // wait for loader to disappear
            browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loader), 15000);

            // click on load more button
            loadMoreButton.click();

            // wait for loader to disappear
            browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(loader), 15000);

            // call function
            clickLoadMoreButtonUntilNotDisplayed();
        } else {}
    }, err => {})
};

it('should keep clicking', function ()
  clickLoadMoreButtonUntilNotDisplayed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clickIfThere(){
  var bool = page.loadMoreButton.isDisplayed();
  browser.driver.sleep(0).then(function () {
    if(bool){
      // <Your Code>
      browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(page.loader), 15000);
      page.loadMoreButton.click();
      browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(page.loader), 15000);
      // </Your Code>
      clickIfThere();
    } else {
      console.log("Did NOT find load more button!");
    }
  });
}

it('should keep clicking', function ()
  clickIfThere();
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Kinda yes, as it clicks on load more button until it is not displayed, at which point it returns an error (element not visible) at `page.loadMoreButton.click();`. In short it should click on load more button and stop once it is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is invoking method recursively. You have defined method that checks whether element is displayed. If so - click on it and check again.

It may look more less like that:

```
public checkLoadMoreButton() {
  return page.loadMoreButton.isDisplayed();
}

this.checkLoadMoreButton().then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    page.loadMoreButton.click();
    this.checkLoadMoreButton();
  }
}
```

Comment: Kacper: unfortunately this doesn't work. It doesn't click load more button, like it ignores the function `this.checkLoadMoreButton().then...`. Or I'm doing something wrong? I added `public checkLoadMoreButton()` to page object file as a function `this.checkLoadMoreButton = function() {
  return this.loadMoreButton.isDisplayed();
 };` and then I call it from spec `page.checkLoadMoreButton().then((result) => {
   if (result) {
    page.loadMoreButton.click();
    page.checkLoadMoreButton();
   }
  });`